# Microsoft Offfice 2010 - Backup all settings, templates, layouts?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-word, backup, microsoft-office-2010

I need to format my computer.

I work with large Word files and have very complicated setups of settings, layouts, templates etc. I really want to backup my settings so I can just install Office and keep working where I left-off.

How can I backup everything so I can just start a new installation and have my quicklayouts, templates etc?

Comment: Good first question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[User state migration tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/user-state-migration-tool.aspx) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624352%28v=office.14%29.aspx) is a list of registry settings you may want to manually export and backup.

Comment: Good sources. Does the tool work on Windows 8, it's on a Windows 7 page and while I *assume* it would work, is there verification of compatibility?

Comment: That sounds right. Although I am paranoid when backing up, and will normally just backup the entire drive and later delete stuff I don't need. I use robocopy, or dd to backup.